# Android - Add other values to websettings settextsize

Tags: android

In my application I am using a webview, and in order to increase/decrease text size, I am using `WebSettings().setTextSize` method, but, this method is limited to 5 predefined enum sizes only (SMALLEST, SMALLER, NORMAL, LARGER,LARGEST).
I know I can use `WebSettings().setTextZoom(int)`, but my application is available for API Level 8 and above, and this method was introduced in API Level 14...

My question is: Is there any way to add other sizes to `webSettings().setTextSize`? maybe by extending textSize enum, or define other sizes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`WebSettings.setDefaultFontSize(int size)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDefaultFontSize%28int%29) function

Comment: Thanks, but i have already tried it, my content contains a long CSS file, so changes made by WebSettings.setDefaultFontSize(int size) will not work...